# What is CriteriaBuilder's literal() method for?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

The documentation says:

> Create an expression for a literal

In the code I see such uses of *cb.literal()*:

```
  Expression<String> wordLiteral = cb.literal(word);
  predicates.add(cb.like(namePath, wordLiteral));
```

But if omit *wordLiteral* here and use *word* instead, nothing changes. So what is this method for?

Answer (score 4):

In case of `like` it works, because it does have [overloaded versio](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#like-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-java.lang.String-)n that takes String as an argument.

There are several other methods for Predicate creation that accept only expressions.

For the sake of example lets take [length](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#length-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-). There is only one, and it takes `Expression<String>` as an argument. If we have entity `User` with field `account` and based on user input we must find users whose `account` has same length, that can be done as follows:

```
String accountInput = "Jack";

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);

Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);

cq.select(root)
   .where(
        cb.equal(
            cb.length(root.get("account")),
            cb.length(cb.literal(accountInput))
        )
);
```